# nodejs Q.all promises on function calling itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I need to make a request to get a list of html, and I need to scan it and loop through it and make more requests for each item in the list found, and those might have lists inside them, and so on till theres none left.

I need a way to keep track of all the requests called and call another function when they're done. The tricky bit is the function calls itself over and over for any list items found in the HTML.

The problem I'm having is using Q promises the only promises it waits for are from first request made, and I cant understand why assuming node works like I think it does, see code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var request = require('request');

var allPromises = [];
var finalArray = [];

var start = function(id) {

  var deferred = Q.defer(); 

  request.get({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/id/' + id
  }, function() {

    _.each(body.items, function(index) {

      var item = this;

      finalArray.push(item);

      if(item.hasMore) {
        start(item.id);
      }
    }

    deferred.resolve();

  });

  allPromises.push(deferred.promise);

}

console.log('Starting');

start(1);

Q.all(allPromises).done(function (values) {
  console.log('All Done');
});
```

What I thought happens is:

1 - starts() is called for the first time and the first deferred var is created
2 - the first request is made and the first created deferred variable is pushed to the promises array
3 - Q.all is called and waits

4 - The first request's callback is called 
5 - if the request contains body.x, start() is called again with a new id
6 - a new promises is created and pushed and a new request is made
7 - the first promise is resolved

assuming this only went one level deep

8 - the second promise is resolved
9 - Q.all calls its callback

but in practice, Q.all calls its callback after the first promise, it doesn't wait for any others even though the second promise is pushed before the first promise is resolved.

Why? And how can I make this work?

**Update** forgot to add the loop inside the request callback.

Comment: When `Q.all` is called there is only one promise in the array so it will only wait for this one to be resolved, even if the array is modified. I don't have time to post a complete answer but try resolving a parent promise only if all the children links are resolved. Recursively, passing the promises around, it should work.

Comment: But i dint understand how there is only one promise in the array, is the JS is really synconous and only the io is async, the next promice ahould be added before tye first ome is resolves, so ur saying reguardless.. It'll only rrsolves the ones in it when its called.. That males sense then i guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to edited question:

```
var request = require('request');

var finalArray = [];

var start = function(id) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    request.get({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/id/' + id
    }, function() {

        var subitems = [];
        _.each(body.items, function(index) {

            var item = this;

            finalArray.push(item);

            if(item.hasMore) {
                subitems.push(start(item.id));
            }
        }
        if (subitems.length) {
            deferred.resolve(Q.all(subitems)); // resolve result of Q.all
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

start(1).done(function() {
    console.log('All Done');
});
```

@Bergi's code

```
var request = require('request');

var start = function(id) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    request.get({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/id/' + id
    }, function(err, body) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);
        else deferred.resolve(body);
    });
    return deferred.promise.then(function(body) {
        var finalArray = [];
        return Q.all(_.map(body.items, function(index) {
            var item = this;
            finalArray.push(item);
            if(item.hasMore)
                return start(item.id);
            else
                return [];
        })).then(function(moreResults) {
            return finalArray.concat.apply(finalArray, moreResults);
        });
    });
}

start(1).then(function(finalArray) {
    console.log('All Done');
});
```

Comment: this looks great, but I forgot to add the loop within the request callback, can this solution still work with it? See updated example.

Comment: @Ezra - I believe I've modified the answer to suit the "new" question

Comment: Can you try to promisify at the lowest level only, and move the recursive calls and the array stuff in a separate promise callback?

Comment: @Bergi - looking at the code, I'm sure there could be a more elegant solution, I'm not even sure the updated answer works at all (I do usually test any answer I'm not 100% sure of, but I didn't this time)

Comment: @Bergi - edited again, not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: Let me try - sorry for hijacking your answer :-)

Comment: @Bergi - all good, and I like the fact that there's no global `finalArray` too

Comment: @Bergi, this dosen't work. 'All done' calls after the first request is done.

Comment: Nope, your current one does not work either, the one you had before it did though.

Comment: @Ezra: Are you sure you have the right `return`s everywhere? I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: @Bergi pretty sure, though I really don't understand what exactly is going on in it.